# Spring Cloud Data Flow app with separate sink and source

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have this application that I would like to deploy using SCDF. It receives a message (sink), processes it asynchronously through a non deterministic or simple pipeline system. At the end, it might or might not produce an output. If an output is produced I would like to produce a message (source) for other applications to consume. The application can not be split into more than one jvm, but more than one instance can be running with no problems. I have found examples that have a source and sink on the same app, but they are connected end to end, which is not my case. Anybody has solved this problem, any hints?

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by "I have found examples that have a source and sink on the same app, but they are connected end to end, wich is not my case. " ? Are you referring to the Spring Cloud Stream aggregate applications?

Comment: The one example I found, doing exactly the opposite of what I need:https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/double

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking at something similar to what is discussed here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/915.

Comment: No, I do not need an standalone application, it is very much an application connected to the flow. On one side consumes message and on other side produces messages, but on different threads...